Show woocommerce add to cart button on product page even when out of stock
We want to display the add to cart button button woocommerce when product is out of stock.
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_is_purchasable_callback', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'filter_is_purchasable_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_is_purchasable_callback( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        return $purchasable;
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart'); 
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart'); 
}

In dashboard > WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Inventory > "Out of Stock Visibility" is unchecked
Stock management is set to Track stock quantity for this product
Allow backorders? is set to do allow
Stock quantity is 0
Tried the above code but nothing seems to happen
The above code was entered in the child theme's function.php but the add to cart button still did not display when product is out of stock.
